# Failed to parse Packages/manifest.json

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling, admob, appodeal

I making a game with Unity and I want to add some ADs. I added AdMob and when it shows AD game is crashing. Now I added appodeal and it crashes every time I start app on my android phone, but in playmode in Unity all OK.

In console I got this error:

> Failed to parse Packages/manifest.json. 
>   Exception:System.MethodAccessException: Method `EDMInternal.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(string)' is inaccessible from method`Google.PackageManifestModifier.ReadManifest()'
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_throw_method_access(intptr,intptr)
>     at Google.PackageManifestModifier.ReadManifest () [0x00039] in Z:\tmp\tmp.SU4iki1OHB\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\PackageManagerResolver\src\PackageManifestModifier.cs:89 
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
>   Google.PackageManifestModifier:ReadManifest() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.SU4iki1OHB/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PackageManagerResolver/src/PackageManifestModifier.cs:91)
>   Google.PackageManagerResolver:UpdateManifest(ManifestModificationMode, Boolean, Boolean, IEnumerable`1) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.SU4iki1OHB/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PackageManagerResolver/src/PackageManagerResolver.cs:329)
>   Google.PackageManagerResolver:CheckRegistries() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.SU4iki1OHB/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PackageManagerResolver/src/PackageManagerResolver.cs:117)
>   Google.PackageManagerResolver:m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.SU4iki1OHB/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PackageManagerResolver/src/PackageManagerResolver.cs:78)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:486)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:m__B() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:536)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested(Boolean) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
>   Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

Also I got these warnings:

> Cannot add menu item 'Assets/External Dependency Manager/Android Resolver/Display Libraries' for method 'PlayServicesResolver.MenuDisplayLibraries' because a menu item with the same name already exists.
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
>
> Cannot add menu item 'Window/Google/Game Package Registry/Settings' for method 'PackageManagerResolver.ShowSettingsAlias' because a menu item with the same name already exists.
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

And 17 warnings like these.

I use this code to show AD in appodeal:

```
private void Initialize(bool isTesting)
{
    Appodeal.setTesting(isTesting);
    Appodeal.muteVideosIfCallsMuted(true);
    Appodeal.initialize(APP_KEY, Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL | Appodeal.NON_SKIPPABLE_VIDEO);
}

public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (Appodeal.isLoaded(Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL))
    {
        Appodeal.show(Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL);
    }
}
```

I don't know what I can do. Help me please.

Comment: Just leaving a comment because I'm encountering the same warnings such as this: "Cannot add menu item 'Assets/External Dependency Manager/Android Resolver/Display Libraries' for method 'PlayServicesResolver.MenuDisplayLibraries' because a menu item with the same name already exists.".

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old question, but maybe my solution would be helpful in case someone will face same problem. In my case I had two different versions of ExternalDependencyManager in the project. I checked Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor folder and there were duplicated libraries v1.2.152 and v1.2.150. I removed all files with v1.2.150 version and error had gone.